# Already have EC2 Instance Running Wordpress, How to Create/Configure Auto Scaling & Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

This is probably an inane question for those of you experienced in AWS but I've been googling a few hours and really need a straightforward guide. I have configured my site running bitnami wordpress on one T2 Micro EC2 instance.

I'm going to launch the site soon but would like it to elastically scale with demand. This might be an oversimplified question, but how do I set this up? Do I make a second instance from the same EBS volume and balance load between them? I'm just a little lost. Any guidance on where to start configuring scalability for a single EC2 instance would be very very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To load balance your traffic you will need to configure ELB. To auto-scale your instance you will need to configure auto-scaling group. Once you are done with the wordpress configuration on your EC2 instance follow the below steps :

1. Create an AMI of your EC2 instance. Ref :
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html
2. Create a classic load balancer Ref : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html
3. Create launch configuration using the AMI created in step 1. Ref :
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/create-launch-config.html
4. Create an auto-scaling group using launch configuration created in step 3. Ref :
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/create-asg.html
   (At step 6.f. in this link you will need to use ELB that you created
   in step 2).

All the AWS docs/guides provide step by step explanation of how to configure things and hence I haven't provided more details in above steps but the sequence of steps that you need to perform.

Comment: Also,  don't instal Database in the EC2 where WordPress is installed. Use RDS for database. AWS provides as service  called Elastic Beanstalk, a PaaS where you can host scalable and Highly available web application. You can refer to the AWS step by step document below to host a highly available WordPress site if you are interested using Elastic Beanstalk.     https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html

Comment: I appreciate this but am still quite lost. I followed your guide but on step two I couldn't get the ELB working for bitnami wordpress. It returned a 503 error. Does something special need to be done like duplicating the EC2 instance in the a different availability zone? Thank you!

Comment: @Scotchnowplease I'm in the process of composing a screen share video. I upload it in a couple of hours.

Comment: @MichaelAbabio YOU ARE A SAVOIR. Hahah I've been struggling with this all day.

Comment: Sorry @Scotchnowplease someone deleted my entry. Check this video out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=so0CuPhjDTQ